# How to freeze pane/fix website header and horizontal nav bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I currently have a banner/header as well as a horizontal navigation menu below this header that I would like to freeze pane/fix, so that any content below this header/nav just scrolls beneath it, always.

FYI, I need it to work in IE8.

I have setup the following skeleton structure of this as follows:

```
    <div id="banner-nav">
      <div id="banner">
        <div id="nav">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>
```

If it cannot be done on the above fashion, any other alternatives that would accomplish my requirement would be great.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<div id="banner-nav">
```

to

```
<div id="banner-nav" style="position:fixed">
```

Comment: thanks for this but actually tried this and didn't work in IE8.

Comment: can you post the styles of banner-nav and banner?

Comment: position fixed works in IE8 as long as you are not working in quirks mode. remember to include a doctype. position:fixed or position:absolute are the way to go.

Comment: When I placed the postion:fixed on the banner-nav div it completely made a mess of things. My header within the banner div got sliced in half. Any idea what could be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply fixed positioning to your `banner-nav` element:

```
#banner-nav {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

To get this to work in IE7+, you need a `doctype` that makes the browser render in "standards mode". The HTML5 doctype should do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```